# Writing a value in Firebase Realtime Database takes forever

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to learn firebase realtime database for web apps but I cannot seem to resolve one issue. When I run this file (which should just update a record in Firebase DB), it never stops running. So to sum it up:

1. I run this file
2. It adds a new record to my realtime DB
3. It never stops running

wtf?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import "firebase/compat/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ** ,
    authDomain: ** ,
    projectId: ** ,
    storageBucket: ** ,
    messagingSenderId: ** ,
    appId: ** ,
    databaseURL: "mydatabaseurl"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let database = firebase.database();

export function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture: imageUrl
    });
}

writeUserData("name", "a", "a", "a")
```

I followed [their tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) but no hope there.

Comment: What do you mean by "run this file"?  Web apps don't really "run files".  They execute javascript in the context of an HTML document.  It's also not clear what you mean by "it never stops running".  How are you observing this?  How do we duplicate this behavior for ourselves?  Please edit the question to be clear on these points.

Comment: Performance problems are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot remotely, so I recommend: 1) including very specific numbers, like "executing this line of code takes X seconds" - preferably by including log statements (and their output). 2) See if you can reproduce the problem with a tool like stackblitz.com. so that we can all look at it and give it a try.